# Statistics: Hypothesis testing to find p-value

Tags: normal-distribution, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

I am currently writing a thesis in machine learning and I am trying to use t-test to show that my model is better than the current state of the art. The dataset I used has 16 different tasks and each of the mean performance and the number of dataset for each task are as below:

> dataset =
> [2690,76,55,898,3758,69,787,392,1547,451,202,184,283,66,152,5271]
>
> comparison1=
> [84.6,86.3,87.2,81.1,91.1,76.5,92.6,88.4,82.7,96.2,78.1,95.8,85.4,69.0,82.0
> ,83.6]
>
> proposed =
> [85.8,87.2,90.8,81.4,91.4,81.5,92.8,88.2,84.9,96.4,77.9,96.5,84.8,69.1,
> 78.2,84.1]

I would like to find out whether my model has improved or not using t-test and so far I calculated it by creating a new list that repeats or replicate the mean performance by the corresponding number of dataset.

> (e.g. full_comparison1 = [comparison1[0]]*dataset[0]+[comparison1[1]]*dataset[1]+[comparison1[2]]*dataset[2]...

Then, I used scipy from python to calculate p-value:

> scipy.stats.ttest_ind(full_proposed , full_comparison1 , equal_var=True)
>
> Ttest_indResult(statistic=13.868700994408345,
> pvalue=1.2916487642703654e-43)

This result tells that the difference is significant, but it seems that p-value is way too small. Could somebody please let me know whether I have done it correctly or not?
Thank you so much!!

Comment: What does ```full_comparison1``` represent?

Comment: How does the primary literature address this topic? The best reference I have is: [Benavoli, Alessio, et al. "Time for a change: a tutorial for comparing multiple classifiers through Bayesian analysis." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 18.1 (2017): 2653-2688.](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume18/16-305/16-305.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea from your description whether
samples `comp` and `prop` both of size $n = 16$
are intended to be independent samples, or paired
element-by-element.

Both `comp` and `prop` pass Shapiro-Wilk tests as
consistent with sampling from normal distributions.
And normal Q-Q plots are suitably linear. So it seems
safe to do t tests.

However, both have sample means near $85$ and in R neither a 2-sample Welch t test
nor a paired t.test gives a significant result.

```
summary(comp)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  69.00   81.78   85.00   85.04   89.08   96.20 
summary(prop)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  69.10   81.47   85.35   85.69   90.95   96.50
```

The high correlation between `comp` and `prop` seems
to indicate paired data---as does the scatterplot.

```
cor(comp, prop)
[1] 0.9649813

stripchart(list(comp, prop), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

[image]

```
plot(comp, prop, pch=20)
 abline(a=0, b= 1, col="blue")
```

[image]

The P-value $0.1914 > 0.05 = 5\%$ does not show
a significant difference.

```
t.test(comp,prop, pair=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  comp and prop
t = -1.368, df = 15, p-value = 0.1914
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.6627189  0.3627189
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                  -0.65
```

The t-statistic $T=-1.368,$ can also be
found as shown in the R code below:

```
d = comp-prop
mean(d)/(sd(d)/sqrt(16))
[1] -1.368042
```

For the record, a two-sample Welch t test also gives non-significant P-value $0.799.$

```
t.test(comp,prop)$p.val
[1] 0.799499
```

Bottom line: From what you show, I cannot figure out how you
did which t test nor explain your P-values. Please
edit your question for clarity if I have missed
something.